# Encapsulating Logic in Pages using GEB and Cucumber

Tags: groovy, cucumber, bdd, geb

Using GEB I was using the Page Object Pattern to encapsulate information about the different pages statically.

I then refactored my GEB code to be used from a separate class so I could encapsulate common commands using method calls.

For example I would have a method login() which will call the appropriate GEB code to login to the website that I am testing. I would then have other common functions using method calls on a TestHelper class.

I wanted to move these common functions to the Pages that they act upon. For example a search page would have a search method, the login page would have the login method. This way I can build a library of pages which have all the common functionality on them for use across multiple GEB projects. Now to do this each page must have a handle on the geb.Browser therefore I would now have to instantiate each page in the test setup. By doing so I am no longer able to use the standard page object pattern.

```
to ReviewQueuePage
assert at(ReviewQueuePage)
```

The code above will throw a null pointer as the object is no longer able to be accessed in a static manner meaning I had to change the code to

```
go ReviewQueuePage.url
```

This removes all the functionality of using the class as a Page.

Does anyone have any solutions for encapsulating the data for each of the pages in way that it doesn't cause the pages to act differently.

Answer (score 5):

This resource maybe of interest to you. http://adhockery.blogspot.com/2010/11/encapsulating-page-state-and-actions-in.html. It also has examples in [git](https://github.com/robfletcher/geb-examples).

This also might be useful [Passing state between pages when using geb & spock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3631227/passing-state-between-pages-when-using-geb-spock)

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit confused.  Are you looking for a way to share common code among multiple pages?  This is the impression I get after reading your question several times, but I'm not quite sure.  You mentioned "common functions".  Well, common components can be encapsulated using Module objects.  In each page that uses a common component, simply reference the module object in the page object.

Comment: Sorry I'm looking to encapsulating common functions on the pages that they act upon and then sharing the pages amongst different projects. I'll have a look at Module objects.

Comment: Have a look at the entire Geb manual (cover to cover) before you continue any of your development efforts.  It is a must-read if you are using Geb.  No skimming allowed.